# summarizer won't work with list as attribute

Tags: python, pipeline, summarize

I use the pipeline in python to summarize reviews

This code works and gives me the summary:

```
    article = 'Everything is good and clean, but the swimming pool does not work at this time, according to their words, they say maintenance and God knows Parking needs umbrellas Breakfast is good and the bed is excellent and comfortable and the view of the room is great.'
    text = summarizer(article)[0]['summary_text']
```

But this doesn't work:

```
text = summarizer(chunks[0])[0]['summary_text']
```

despite `chunks[0]` containing the same text as `article`

And the error is: [image]

Why won't it work? what should I do? I need to summarize all items of `chunks` in a loop

Edit:

I solve it by reducing the size of `chunks[0]` so the summarizer could accept it.

Comment: What does the output look like if you print `chunks[0]`?

Comment: @BeRT2me a simple text like `article`

Comment: @BeRT2me I solve it by reducing the size of `chunks[0]` so the summarizer could accept it.